# fsck.ext4 consumes all memory and gets killed

Tags: ext4, fsck, external-hdd

I have a probably corrupted external hard disc that I need to check for errors and fix them. I can't create any new directory on it and get the following errors:

```
2216505.217508] EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended                                                                   │
└Feb  7 17:31:18 Ganymed kernel: [2216505.326946] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)                                                                         │
┌Feb  7 17:31:18 Ganymed kernel: [2216505.217508] EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended                                                                   │
│Feb  7 17:31:18 Ganymed kernel: [2216505.326946] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)                                                                         │
│Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.379474] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 3920, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 24031 vs 24544 free clusters  │
│Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.391046] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 3936, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 24031 vs 24544 free clusters  │
│Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.405316] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 3952, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 23991 vs 24544 free clusters  │
│Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.417718] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 3968, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 23991 vs 24544 free clusters  │
│Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.429068] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 3984, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 23991 vs 24544 free clusters  │
│Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.433767] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 4000, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 24248 vs 24544 free clusters  │
│Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.447223] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 4016, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 3 vs 24544 free clusters      │
│Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.459589] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 4032, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 24055 vs 24544 free clusters  │
│Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.463687] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 4048, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 0 vs 24544 free clusters      │
└Feb  7 17:31:34 Ganymed kernel: [2216521.467055] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:805: group 4064, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 24029 vs 24544 free clusters
```

So I tried to run `fsck -f /dev/sda1`. As recommended here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/155873. But after quite some time it keeps aborting with `signal 9`:

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts                                                
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
fsck: Warning... fsck.ext4 for device /dev/sda1 exited with signal 9.
```

I tried several times. Can somebody please give me a hint, what could be the cause of fsck to fail. Is there another method I could try to fix the disk?

**UPDATE:** At first I thought this might be a bug in `e2fsck` and updated to a newer version – from `e2fsck 1.44` (Raspbian Buster) to `e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)` (Raspbian Bullseye). But as the same error occurs with the newer version I started thinking this might be the only solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/9218/running-out-of-memory-running-fsck-on-large-filesystems
Here it is suggested to create `/etc/e2fsck.conf` with the following contents:

```
[scratch_files]
directory = /var/cache/e2fsck
```

I tried this, but I am still running our of memory on my 4GB system.
Actually at 95 % the process starts to consume all memory and gets killed as a result:

```
pi@Ganymed ~ $ sudo e2fsck -fp /dev/sda1
Signal (6) SIGABRT si_code=SI_TKILL =============================   | 95.0%       
pi@Ganymed ~ $ sudo e2fsck -fp /dev/sda1
Signal (6) SIGABRT si_code=SI_TKILL =============================   \ 95.0%    
pi@Ganymed ~ $
```

**UPDATE 2:** I connected the external hd to a more powerful machine with 16 GB memory and a multicore AMD64 processor. Here the repair process ran smoothly:

```
  sudo e2fsck -fp /dev/sde1
/dev/sde1: Journal wird wiederhergestellt
/dev/sde1: Auffüllbyte am Ende der Inode-Bitmap ist nicht gesetzt. REPARIERT.  
/dev/sde1: 3451100/244187136 Dateien (0.4% nicht zusammenhängend), 163473991/976745984 Blöcke
```

Unfortunately I did not log the memory usage during the process...
Maybe this is a bug in the ARM version?

Answer (score -1):

Note the messages:-

```
EXT4-fs (sda1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

It is **very** strongly recommended that `e2fsck` is only run on unmounted filesystems.

Comment: As far as I know it's not even possible to run it on mounted devices. Hence the error messages you are citing weren't caused by `e2fsck`, but rather made me run `e2fsck` in the first place.

Comment: Its absolutely necessary in the case of the root filesystem - but when that is required the filesystem is (re)mounted read-only (fsck access the block device directly so can still carry out repairs).